# Google Closure basic information

Tags: javascript, google-closure

I've been assigned a task to learn and work on Google closures but I'm not able to find any suitable tutorials and examples where i can learn closures in a systematic manner.

Comment: closures not equal to google closure

Comment: ok but how do i go about it? any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint; it's in the name (google).

googling for "google closure" first hit https://developers.google.com/closure/

Google closure consist of the closure library and closure compiler (and some other tools like soy templates and css language). Closure compiler is used to minify, check type, flatten namespaces and remove unused code from your JavaScript code files.

The closure library is a library of code you can use in your code and it'll compile with your code http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_base.js.html (at the moment their site is down though).

There are books that you can read, I found closure the definitive guide by Michael Bolin very helpful. It's an old book but many of the things in the book are still valid.

Comment: i'm Trying to design a simple login page but im struck up! can some one suggest me how to create the UI(i,e text area and buttons) using google closure itself?